# Python, MySQL, MAMP - How to do it?

Tags: php, python, mysql, mamp

The short version of the story is that when I `import MySQLdb` in a script that I run from the browser, I always get `500 Internal Server Error`.

The longer version:

Trying to learn web programming concepts. So far I've done a lot of work with PHP and MySQL using MAMP. I have created a big Javascript/PHP app and a big MySQL db to go with it. Now I'd like to learn Python, and I'd like to start with a familiar environment, namely, my MAMP setup and the db I've created.

I run my PHP scripts by entering `localhost:8888/the-script.php` in my browser. Now I have python scripts that run the same way, so I know python is working in my MAMP environment. What I haven't figured out yet is how to get my python scripts to talk to the MySQL db.

I installed Django, and I got it to see my db, but it wants to run its own server. I don't want that. I want my python scripts to run on the same server as my PHP scripts (I suppose I could try to get my PHP scripts to run on the Django server, but I'd rather consider that a last resort, to be taken only in desperation).

I've tried installing various packages with pip and macports, and I can run python from the command line and `import MySQLdb`, and it works fine. I've been all over stackoverflow and tried many of the applicable suggestions. I found a straightforward set of installation [instructions](http://dreamconception.com/tech/how-to-install-mysqldb-mysql-python-on-mamp/) that I thought might be the answer. But if I `import MySQLdb` in a script that I run from the browser, I always get `500 Internal Server Error`.

I was hoping to learn python without first having to get a PhD in a lot of other areas like how Apache works internally, rebuilding MAMP and MySQL from the source code, etc. I realize that learning web programming concepts will eventually include those things, but I'm not ready for that. Right now I just want to learn python.

Is there a simple way to get a python script to run in the same environment as my PHP scripts, and interact with the same MySQL db that I've created for use with my PHP scripts?

Comment: Did you solve this yet?